# React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At the start I will say that I know that there are similiar questions, but sadly I couldn't find any answer there.. since most of theme was about `getInitialState` problem
I'm strugglig here trying to fetch data to the view from an array the has `id,name and surname.`
It seems that is almost works beside the error part that It wont to render it 
Error description that I got in console:

```
React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. 
It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). 
Check the render method of `Reapeter`.
```

Does it have something to do with it to being specified like .toString()? or something. I've got no idea to be honest, Im a react newbie.

```
var Reapeter = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    var foreach = this.props.data.map(function(HeaderMiniComment){
        return(
            <HeaderMiniComment name={HeaderMiniComment.name} surname={HeaderMiniComment.surname} key={HeaderMiniComment.id}/>
        )
    });
    return(
        <div>
            {foreach}
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

@Edit
If there is lack of info, tell me. I'll try to bring more @_ @

@the HeaderMiniComment

```
var HeaderMiniComment = React.createClass({
render:function(){
    return(
        <div>
            <span><p>{this.props.name}</p></span>
            <br />
            <span style={{color:'red'}}><p>{this.props.surname}</p></span>
        </div>
    )
}
});
```

Comment: How looks your `props.data`? I'm afraid that there are no components `HeaderMiniComment`

Comment: Seems like `HeaderMiniComment` is either `null`, `undefined`, a boolean or a number. Check your data.

Comment: @jonzee edited, added the headerminicomment

Comment: So, in `<HeaderMiniComment name={HeaderMiniComment.name} .. />` you expect the first `HeaderMiniComment` to refer to something else than the second `HeaderMiniComment` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, you should keep in `props.data` only data for `HeaderMiniComment`, and implement map as here (`HeaderMiniComment` is outer component)

```
var foreach = this.props.data.map(function(item){
    return(
        <HeaderMiniComment name={item.name} surname={item.surname} key={item.id}/>
    )
});

var HeaderMiniComment = React.createClass({
render:function(){
    return(
        <div>
            <span><p>{this.props.name}</p></span>
            <br />
            <span style={{color:'red'}}><p>{this.props.surname}</p></span>
        </div>
    )
}
});

data = [{id: 1, name: 'John', surname: 'Kennedy'}, {...}, ...];
```

Comment: This seems to fixed the problem. Is the (item) a custom name or it is something built up for .map?

Comment: Nope, you can name it as you want :)

Comment: @Harugawa: How did you expect the same variable to refer to two different things in the same context? Or is it ignorance about how JSX works? What if you had written `React.createElement(HeaderMiniComment. {name: HeaderMiniComment.name})`. Is the mistake more obvious for you here?

Comment: Funny, why did (HeaderMiniComment), was it confusing referance to the returned <HeaderMiniComment /> in foreach @_ @? Guess, it was just dumb me, lesson learnt.

Comment: @Harugawa: `<HeaderMiniComment />` is syntactic sugar for `React.createClass(HeaderMiniComment)`, i.e. the value of the variable `HeaderMiniComment` is passed to `React.createClass`.

Comment: You don't understand how callbacks works, in JS you pass to `map` callback (some function) which is triggered with every element of array as a argument, read something about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/map

Comment: I think.. confused it... was kind of following a documentation where they wrote <Comment /> and then function(comment). Now I see it was with small, so it was different cause of lower case.